# ASP.NET 5 Access session in custom Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to do a custom Policy for my BaseController. The purpose for this policy is to prevent the repetition of code in every other controller.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("PolicyName", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddRequirements(*INSERT POLICY HERE*);
    });
});
```

I'm **Trying** to add the policy like this in the **ConfigureServices** method in Startup.cs

What's the catch?

I want to access the Session in my policy because I need it in my calculations. I do that using the dependency injection of **IHttpContextAccessor**.

The problem arises in the *INSERT POLICY HERE* part. Because I'm supposed (from what I saw online) to do: `new MyPolicy()`

But that doesn't work because it needs the `IHttpContextAccessor`.

How can I pass it into the policy? And if there are better ways of doing this please feel free to share

Answer (score 0):

The examples you've seen online are simplified, but you don't have to have the policy and the requirements in the same class. Requirements are basically data - for example an age requirement would hold the age you wish to check. So, separate the requirement into its own class, then you can new it up without the DI problem, and policy will be newed up as required via the DI container.

Comment: I'm gonna try this soon. Sorry for the late feedback but I just haven't been able to pick this up

Comment: So I have a SessionUtils class (so I don't have to use always the same operations in every policy I make). This class uses the IHttpContextAccessor. How do I include it in the requirement? Or is a SessionUtils class a bad idea?

Comment: So you can implement multiple handlers for requirements (I'm writing the documentation right now actually). A handler can also handler multiple requirements. So, for example, if you wanted a door access requirement you'd write one handler which checks if an employee has his badge, and one which checks if the current identity is a security guard, then register both handlers in the service collection. Then when a policy wants that requirement it checks *both* handlers, and if either succeed the policy passes.

Comment: And as handler can implement AuthorizationHandler<T>, a single handler could handle multiple requirements too, thus you could have a single handler that works for multiple policies and multiple requirements.

Comment: And it's now documented. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html

Comment: I use HttpContext in my Policy too, but HttpContext.Session raised always an exception : "InvalidOperationException", but in my controller, the session is here with my datas ! I registered correctly Session middleware before Mvc in Startup. Any ideas ?